# Cant get NLog to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

So I set up NLog config file supposedly correct (did the same thing i did on a working project) however in this project it fails for some reason the database Logs table is empty. Can somone tell me what may cause the issue?

Heres the code

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller    
{ 
       private ShopModel db = new ShopModel();
       private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("dbloger");
       public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            logger.Info("Test");
            return View(db.Users);
        }
}
```

NLog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
  <targets async="true">

    <target name="dbl" xsi:type="Database" connectionStringName="ShopModel"
           dbProvider="System.Data.EntityClient"
           commandText=" INSERT INTO Logs ([Usrname] ,[Log], [Date]) VALUES (@Email,@Message, @Date);" >

      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}"/>
      <parameter name="@Date" layout="${longdate}" />
      <parameter name="@Email" layout="${gdc:Email}" />

    </target >
  </targets>

  <rules>

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dbl" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And connection string in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>

 <add name="ShopModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ShopModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Shopdb.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You cannot use Entity Framework's connection string. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45202964/296861).

Comment: Where should i derive the connection string from? I don't think i have a startup.cs in my project, i also tried setting connectionString tag to the one thats inside my web.config but that didn't work.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't use web.config except for hosting in IIS. Place the connection string inside `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Oh dang it, i feel stupid, my project is a regular asp.net web application not asp.net core

Comment: I see. Anyhow, you can place `internalLogLevel="Warn"      internalLogFile="C:\temp\internal-nlog.txt"` to see the nlog error.

Comment: Ok so i get a     `2017-07-20 17:53:43.5138 Error Error initializing target 'Database Target[dbl_wrapped]'. Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.It may not be installed.
   in System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   in NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.InitializeTarget()
   in NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration)` exception, also i am using visual studio 2017 and also have 2013 installed on my pc could it cause a problem?

Comment: Another thing is that my old project works on both 2017 and 2013, so the problem is in the new project .

Comment: Please make sure you have correct provider name `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`, if you use SQL Server. Not `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`. ***Again, you cannot use Entity Frameworks connection string for NLog.***

Comment: OK i now seem to understand it, the connection provider tag for the connection string in web.config is System.Data.EntityClient therefore it doesn't work with NLog, am i right? If so what can i do to get around this?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a variable inside nlog file, and assign the connection string value from ***Startup.cs***.

```
<connectionString>${var:connectionString}</connectionString>
```

### [nlog.config](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/nlog.config#L24)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!--
  NOTE: Use this to log internal error, if you have issue configuring NLog.

  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="C:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">
-->

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
      <connectionString>${var:connectionString}</connectionString>
      <!-- 
          Script for creating the dbo.Log table.

          SET ANSI_NULLS ON
          GO
          SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
          GO
          CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs](
              [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
              [Application] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
              [Logged] [datetime] NOT NULL,
              [Level] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
              [Action] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
              [Controller] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
              [Identity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
              [Referrer] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
              [UserAgent] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
              [Url] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
              [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
              [Logger] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
              [Callsite] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
              [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
           CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
          (
              [Id] ASC
          )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
          ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

          GO
        -->
      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO dbo.Logs (Application,Logged,[Level],Action,Controller,[Identity],Referrer,UserAgent,Url,Message,Logger,Callsite,Exception)
        VALUES (@Application,@Logged,@Level,@Action,@Controller,@Identity,@Referrer,@UserAgent,@Url,@Message,@Logger,@Callsite,@Exception);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@Application" layout="ASP" />
      <parameter name="@Logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@Action" layout="${aspnet-MVC-Action}" />
      <parameter name="@Controller" layout="${aspnet-MVC-Controller}" />
      <parameter name="@Identity" layout="${aspnet-User-Identity}" />
      <parameter name="@Referrer" layout="${aspnet-Request-Referrer}" />
      <parameter name="@UserAgent" layout="${aspnet-Request-UserAgent}" />
      <parameter name="@Url" layout="${aspnet-Request-Url}" />
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@CallSite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />
      <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- Skip Microsoft logs, and log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

### [Startup.cs](http://Startup.cs)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        app.AddNLogWeb();
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = 
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        ...
    }
}
```

}

### Update

Based on comment, you are using ASP.NET MVC. You cannot use Entity Framework Connection string for NLog. Instead, you will need to have a separate connection string like this -

```
<add name="CONNECTION_STRING_NAME_FOR_NLOG" 
         connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Shopdb.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the connection string provider which is `System.Data.EntityClient` which is currently not supported by NLog
[Found here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/98)

Comment: NLog 4.5 adds support for Entity Framework ConnectionString, so they can be referenced directly. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2510